# Delete individual image using jquery dynamic selector inside php foreach

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to delete images inside a folder, where I am using PHP `glob()` to access them individually & then using `jquery-leanmodal` to pop up confirmation as form, then sending request through `$.post()`, so that page doesn't need refreshing.

But, its not working.

**Question**

Any guesses, where I am doing wrong ?

**What I am trying to do**

I am grabbing all images from a folder using glob. Then I display them in a webpage in a table. In the table I link each image to a deletion option (via `href`). To delete an image the user clicks the link which runs a jQuery script that causes a confirmation pop-up form to display. Upon confirmation a `$.post();` query runs which is directed to a url that contains code to delete the linked file/image.

**What is happening / output**

When the user clicks the link the URL changes to, for example, `.php#imagename_jpg` but no pop-up confirmation form is displayed.

Code is working well without foreach.

NOTE: I have put all comments in code in lines. I hope it is easy to understand now.

```
<?php
  $dirname = "../assets/img/logos/";
  $images = glob($dirname."*.{jpg,png,gif,tiff,jpeg,JPG}", GLOB_BRACE); //using PHP `glob()` to access images inside path, individually

  foreach($images as $image) {
    $variable_id = str_replace(".", "_", $image); // creating a dynamic id, from each image-name
?>

// below starting ,code to link - to delete/unlink this image file on clicking `id=modaltrigger`, followed by a pop-up confirmation form.

<p style="text-align: center; font-size: 10px; margin-top: 5px;">
  <a id="modaltrigger_<?=$variable_id ?>" href="#<?=$variable_id ?>" class="btn" style="border: none !important;">Delete</a>
</p> // i hope this code is simple to understand

// pop-up confirmation form
<div id="<?=$variable_id ?>" class="popupContainer" style="display:none;">
  <div class="deleteplogo_<?=$variable_id ?>">
    // some form code to pop-up with submit button & `action=post`
  </div>
</div>

<!-- jquery : delete image confirmation: pop up based on leanModal jquery UI -->

<script type="text/javascript">
  var magica = <?php echo $variable_id; ?>; // using php variable in jquery
  $('#modaltrigger_'+magica).leanModal({top : 200, overlay : 0.6, closeButton: ".modal_close" }); // variable selector

  $(function() {
    // Calling popUp delete Form on clicking variable-id of ahref above
    $('#modaltrigger_'+magica).click(function() {
      $('.deleteplogo_'+magica).show(); // showing up hidden class above
      //$(".header_title").text('Are you sure , you want to delete?');
      return false;
    });        
  })
</script>

<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: What is it doing that it should not be? What is it not doing that it should be? Dumping a slab of code without any clues is not very helpful

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have put all comments in code in lines. I hope it is easy to understand now. I have explained each n every point in detail.

Comment: change variable_id. That is causing problem. Because it contains the whole image name along with the path. Change that to simple number and check.

Comment: foreach ($images as $image) {

                $imageName = str_replace("path", "", $image);

                $variable_id = str_replace(".", "_", $imageName);

Answer (score 1):

Deleted all AJAX-JQUERY code & used :

file1.php

```
    <td>
    <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 10px; margin-top: 5px;">
    <a id="modaltrigger_<?= $variable_id ?>" href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $imageName; ?>" class="btn"
    style="border: none !important;">Delete</a>
    </p>
    </td>
```

delete.php

```
    <?php

    $filePath = "D:/folder/".$_GET['id'];
    if(is_file($filePath)){
    @unlink($filePath);
    echo ('<strong>SUCCESS! Deleted: &nbsp; <span style="color:red">'. $_GET['id']. '</span>,&nbsp; file from Directory</strong>');
    }
    else if(!unlink($filePath)){ 
    echo ("Error deleting file : ". $_GET['id']. " Already deleted OR doesn't EXIST"); 
    }

    ?>
```

Worked like Charm ! Thanks !